# BigCommerce oauth2 passport.js strategy

Tags: node.js, api, passport.js, bigcommerce

BigCommerce is a huge eCommerce platform and their API and app development is getting really big. Their new API uses oauth2 authentication (grant type = Authorization code). has anyone developed Bigcommerce passport.js Strategy as of yet?

As far as I can see it is like a traditional Authorisation code strategy but initial authorization request isn't kicked off by the application itself, a using logged into their Bigcommerce store will initiate the auth request from the "bigcommerce App store" inside of there bigcommerce store dashboard. Then the app (using node.js and passport.js) will handle the callback url which received the auth code and requests for a Token (from the Bigcommerce api).
I have this process working with simple-oauth2 npm module, but need to figure out the storing of the client access token in MongoDB etc.

Has anyone done this?